# Why gcc -g doesn't work with multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, lldb

To debug my `C` code I compile it with the `-g` flag and use `lldb` to see where my `seg fault` is for example.
I use the `-g` flag so the output of `lldb` is in `C` not `Assembly`.
but now I have a multiple files project and `lldb` shows only `Assembly` even tho I'm using the `-g` flag, it's like the `-g` flag applies only to one file.
Example:

```c
gcc -g example.c
lldb a.out
>run
   I get c code here
```

```c
gcc -g example1.c example2.c main.c
lldb a.out
>run
   I get assembly code here
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm I missing here?
and how can I get c code in `lldb`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe because it's a different program

Comment: correct it was in a library code that's why I got assembly, I got my code when I used up. thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you just `run` the program you shouldn't be getting code at all.

You will be getting code if the program *stops* running. Then you need to look at the call stack to make sure you're actually in your own code.

If you're in library code then it will likely not have source available and you'll get assembler code. Go `up` the call-stack until you reach your own code.

Answer (score 0):

GNU’s documentation for the ‘gcc -g’ says

> Produce debugging information in the operating system’s native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF). GDB can work with this debugging information.

Notice that it makes no mention of either C or assembler.

I imagine that in your first example the error was in your C code; in your second example the error was in a library, such as stdio, for which the debugger doesn’t have C source.

A segmentation fault corresponds to an invalid address. This might mean that you passed invalid data to a library that was expecting a pointer, or you passed a pointer to a buffer but an incorrect length.

A typical error that might cause this is passing a value (v) to a library that is expecting a pointer (&v).